# TCP segmentation fault (core dumped) in C when the program worked fine before

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I copied the code from GeeksForGeeks in order to start making a TCP program. After i ran it a couple of times it worked perfectly... then it suddenly didn't...

Server:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#define MAX 80
#define PORT 8080
#define SA struct sockaddr

void func(int sockfd);

int main()
{
    int sockfd, connfd, len;
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr, cli;

    // socket create and verification
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd == -1) {
        printf("socket creation failed...\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    else
        printf("Socket successfully created..\n");
    bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));

    // assign IP, PORT
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    // Binding newly created socket to given IP and verification
    if ((bind(sockfd, (SA*)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr))) != 0) {
        printf("socket bind failed...\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    else
        printf("Socket successfully binded..\n");

    // Now server is ready to listen and verification
    if ((listen(sockfd, 1)) != 0) {
        printf("Listen failed...\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    else
        printf("Server listening..\n");
    len = sizeof(cli);

    // Accept the data packet from client and verification
    connfd = accept(sockfd, (SA*)&cli, &len);
    if (connfd < 0) {
        printf("server acccept failed...\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    else
        printf("server acccept the client...\n");

    // Function for chatting between client and server
    func(connfd);

    // After chatting close the socket
    close(sockfd);
}

void func(int sockfd)
{
    char buff[MAX];
    int n;
    for(;;)
    {
        bzero(buff, sizeof(buff));
        n=0;

        read(sockfd, buff, sizeof(buff));
        printf("%s", buff);

    }

}
```

Client:

```
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#define MAX 80
#define PORT 8080
#define SA struct sockaddr

void func(int sockfd);

int main()
{
    int sockfd, connfd;
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr, cli;

    // socket create and varification
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd == -1) {
        printf("socket creation failed...\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    else
        printf("Socket successfully created..\n");
    bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));

    // assign IP, PORT
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    // connect the client socket to server socket
    if (connect(sockfd, (SA*)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)) != 0) {
        printf("connection with the server failed...\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("connected to the server..\n");
    }
    printf("boop");
    // function for chat
    func(sockfd);

    // close the socket
    close(sockfd);
}

void func(int sockfd)
{
    printf("Heelloo");
    char buff[MAX];
    int n;
    for(;;)
    {
        bzero(buff, sizeof(buff));
        n=0;

        printf("To client: ");
        while((buff[n++] = getchar()) != '\n');
        write(sockfd, buff, sizeof(buff));


    }
}
```

the function is incomplete but the problem appears to be right before the func() call in client main(). Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Whenever I see a sockets question, I scroll down to the recv/read call to see if 1) The return value has been completely and correctly handled, 2) If library calls that require a NUL-terminated char array are being fed correctly and 3) if the byte-streaming nature of TCP has been handled correctly.......

Comment: Also: 'write(sockfd, buff, sizeof(buff));' why send the whole buff when the line entered is likely shorter?

Comment: i am a beginner in tcp programming and it is too confusing... i do not know how to check either of those things haha :(

Comment: Using getchar in a loop is probably not the best way to get a line of input.  You might want to look into fgets.

Comment: A better tutorial might be [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/).

Answer (score 3):

```
    write(sockfd, buff, sizeof(buff));
```

Every textbook that teaches how to correctly use sockets will explain that you have absolutely no guarantees, whatsoever, that `write()` will actually write the requested number of bytes to the socket. The return value from `write()` indicates the number of bytes that were actually written (which can be less than the number requested by its third parameter), and the code that writes to sockets must correctly implement the necessary to logic to continue writing the remaining data to the socket, if so needed.

Additionally, not the entire `buff` is initialized here, only the initial part of it, so this attempts to write the entire `buff`, which is technically undefined behavior.

```
   read(sockfd, buff, sizeof(buff));
```

The same thing that I explained about `write()` also applies to `read()` as well. You must check the return value from `read()` to determine how much was actually read from the socket. It's entirely possible that the `read()` ends up reading just the first character; the rest of the `buff` is uninitialized, and contains random garbage, and the following `printf`'s search for a properly `'\0'`-terminated strings is doomed to an utter failure, and a crash.

Each time you run your program, for various reasons you're likely end up with different number of bytes both read and written from the socket, by both the client and server. This explains why you observed this program to randomly fail, and seemingly work, with no predictable pattern.

In general, sites like GeeksForGeeks are not meant to be used as means of learning programming; they lack proper tutorials, technical information, and explanatory material. As I mentioned in the beginning, the best way to learn network programming, and other technical topics, is through guided, textbook-based study course. Can you find anything on GeeksForGeeks, where you copied this program from, explain that you ***must*** check the return value from `read` and `write`? No, because it is not meant to be used as a learning material, but ***every*** tutorial on network programming ***must*** explain not just this, but also several other fundamental, related concepts as well.

Comment: Is it better to work with send() and recv()?

Comment: `send` and `recv` work exactly the same way, with respect to the number of bytes read/written. There are minor semantical differences, but, just like with `read` and `write`, you must implement correct logic to handle the actual number of bytes sent or received from the socket.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of bugs in this code, including:

- not saving the return value from read and using it to determine the size of what was read (and maybe null terminating it?)
- using printf with "%s" on a buffer that is not guaranteed to be null terminated and with no length restrictions
- using printf on a buffer that could have nulls internal to the data read (maybe use fwrite  instead of printf?)
- looping infinitely on a socket read instead of checking for errors and terminating the loop
- zeroing a buffer every time it is used (this is a performance issue rather than a functional bug)
- reading data into a buffer in a loop with no buffer size checks in the loop
- sending extraneous data in a buffer to a socket rather than sending only the data intended (you could write n bytes instead of sizeof(buff) bytes)
- not saving the return value from write to make sure all the data was written
- looping infinitely on getchar with no checks for EOF input termination
- looping infinitely on a socket write instead of checking for errors and terminating the loop

Several of these would allow a buffer overrun which could cause a segfault.

Comment: Feel free to repost this bug list on GFG in the appropriate place.  Bad code deserves to be criticized, and doubly so on a help site.