# C Program Attempting to send data, from serveride to client via tcp causing immediate crash

Tags: c

As the title stated - any atempts made by the serverside to send data back to the client result in an imediate crash (segmentation fault). This is a simple tcp chat app - and I am only looking to send strings bidirectionaly between client and server.

Server side below -  the chat() function handles communication , after calling fgets , inputting my string , and attempting to send the data - I get an immediate (segmentation fault) and crash.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <ifaddrs.h>
#define SA struct sockaddr
int chat(int sockfd, int port) {
    
    for (;;) {
        char *buffer_send;
        char *buffer_recv;
        recv(sockfd, buffer_recv, port , 0);
        printf("%s", buffer_recv);                
        printf(":"); fgets(buffer_send, 512, stdin);
        char* exit_func;
        exit_func = strstr(buffer_send, "exit");
            if (exit_func = strstr(buffer_send, "exit")) {
                close(sockfd);
                return 0;
            } else {
                send(sockfd, buffer_send, 512, 0);
        }    
    }
}   

int main () {
    
    int server_socket, new_socket, c;
    struct sockaddr_in socket_address, client;
    server_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (server_socket == -1) {
        printf("socket creation failed! \n");
        return 1;
    }   printf("socket created! \n");
    socket_address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.0.10");
    socket_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    socket_address.sin_port = (8003);
    if( bind(server_socket,(struct sockaddr *)&socket_address , sizeof(socket_address)) < 0) {
        printf("bind failed! \n");
        return 1;
    }   printf("bind done! \n");
    listen(server_socket , 3);
    printf("Waiting for incoming connections...\n");
    c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    new_socket = accept(server_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&client, (socklen_t*)&c);
    if (new_socket<0) {
        printf("accept failed\n");
        return 1;
    }   printf("connection accepted!\n");
    chat(new_socket, socket_address.sin_port);
    return 0;
}
```

however the same way of sending data on my client seems to work fine (without crashing while trying to send data):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <ifaddrs.h>
int chat(int sockfd, int port) {
   
   
   for (;;) {
        char *buffer_send;
        char *buffer_recv;
        printf(":"); fgets(buffer_send, 512, stdin);
        char* exit_func;
        exit_func = strstr(buffer_send, "exit");
            if (exit_func = strstr(buffer_send, "exit")) {
                close(sockfd);
                return 0;
            } else {
                send(sockfd, buffer_send, 512, 0);
        }
        recv(sockfd, buffer_recv, port , 0);
        printf("%s", buffer_recv);   
    }   
}

int main () {
    int target_socket;
    struct sockaddr_in target_server;
    target_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (target_socket == -1) {
        printf("socket creation failed!\n");
        return 1;
    }   printf("socket created!\n");
    target_server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.0.10");
    target_server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    target_server.sin_port = (8003);
    if (connect(target_socket , (struct sockaddr *)&target_server , sizeof(target_server)) < 0) {
        printf("connection failed!\n");
        return 1;
    }   printf("connected!\n");
    chat(target_socket, target_server.sin_port);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char *buffer_recv;` That's an uninitialised pointer. You need to allocate memory and assign it to that pointer. Same for most of the other pointers in your code. As it is, you are writing/reading to random memory which is Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: thats a string.

Comment: Huh? What are you talking about? It's an unitialised pointer and has an indeterminate value.

Comment: sorry , your correct - I replaced it with char buffer_send[512 + 1] = {};
which is not a pointer , but still no luck

Comment: Whenever I see a sockets question, I scroll down to the recv/read call to see if 1) The return value has been completely and correctly handled, 2) If library calls that require a NUL-terminated char array are being fed correctly and 3) if the byte-streaming nature of TCP has been handled correctly.......

Comment: Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67860915/758133

Answer (score 1):

You did not allocated the room for incoming messages, the same for the buffer you want to send. I expect to do some `char buffer_send[512 + 1] = {};` and `char buffer_recv[512 + 1] = {};` to make some place for the message content.

The `+ 1` is added for the extra safety, to not overwrite the NULL terminator when the message received is large enough to fill the entire allocated buffer.

Comment: Umm... what NUL terminator?

Comment: The brace initializer is only guaranteed to be effective the first time the buffer is used.  After that, if the number of bytes loaded is less than the previous call.....  The use of NUL terminators in socket code requires extreme care and is best avoided if at all possible.

Comment: @Martin James The code showed by OP definitely has the other problems to be dealt with. But at least it will not crash by the usage of uninitialised pointers ;)